# Html.DropDownListFor confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

Can someone please help me understand how the Html.DropDownListFor works?
I have a model which is as follows

```
public class TestModel
{
    public IList<SelectListItem> ProductNames { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
}
```

The call to DropDownListFor which looks like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProductNames,  Model.ProductNames, "Select a Product", new {@class="selectproductname" })
```

With this set up I find that the drop down list gets populated correctly however after submitting the form I can't seem to get the selected item. Also from what I've read the call to Html.DropDownListFor should actually look like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product,  Model.ProductNames, "Select a Product", new {@class="selectproductname" })
```

In fact other parts of the code look like that as well but when I do this the drop down list is not being populated. Am I missing something here?

A couple of side notes:
1) The population of this drop down occurs after selection of a value from another drop down so I make an AJAX call by calling getJSON to get data from the database 
2) The application is an MVC application

Would appreciate any help offered. Let me know if you need any other information to help answer this question

Edit:
Here are some more details

This is the action method in the controller used to retrieve the data for the drop down

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadProductsBySupplier(string parentId)
    {
        var ctgy = this._categoryService.GetAllCategoriesByParentCategoryId(Convert.ToInt32(parentId));
        List<int> ctgyIds = new List<int>();

        foreach (Category c in ctgy)
        {
            ctgyIds.Add(c.Id);
        }

        var prods = this._productService.SearchProducts(categoryIds: ctgyIds, storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, orderBy: ProductSortingEnum.NameAsc);

        products = prods.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = m.Id.ToString(),
            Text = m.Name.Substring(m.Name.IndexOf(' ') + 1)
        });

        var p = products.ToList();
        p.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "Select A Product" });
        products = p.AsEnumerable();
        //model.ProductNames = products.ToList();


        return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And this is the JQuery call to the action in the controller

```
$("#Supplier").change(function () {
        var pID = $(this).val();            
        $.getJSON("CoaLookup/LoadProductsBySupplier", { parentId: pID },
                function (data) {
                    var select = $("#ProductNames");
                    select.empty();
                    if (pID != "0") {
                        $.each(data, function (index, itemData) {
                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: itemData.Value,
                                text: itemData.Text
                            }));
                        });
                    }
                });
    });
```

It's this $.each loop that doesn't get entered into when I use model => model.Product even though data is returned in the variable data

Comment: The second usage is correct. The value of `Property` will be the value of the selected option, but you have not shown how you are populating the options in you ajax call so its difficult to know where you problem is.

Comment: Show us how you populated `IList<SelectListItem> ProductNames` It all depends on the `Value` part of `SelectListItem`. As @StephenMuecke said 2nd usage is correct if you assign `Product` value to `Value` part of `ProductNames` ListItem

Comment: when you use `model => model.Product` in ajax success callback use like this `var select = $("#Product")` or `var select = $(".selectproductname")` selector can be `#id` or `.classname`

Comment: Thanks Venkata. I knew it had to be something silly. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second usage is correct, however when you use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product, .....
```

you are generating a `<select>` with the attribute `id="Product"` so you need to change your script to refer to the element with this ID

```
....
$.getJSON("CoaLookup/LoadProductsBySupplier", { parentId: pID }, function (data) {
  var select = $("#Product"); // change this selector
  select.empty();
  ....
```

**Edit**

As a side not, you do not necessarily need to create a `SelectList` in your controller method and you code could be simplified to

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult LoadProductsBySupplier(int parentId)
{
  List<int> ctgyIds = _categoryService.GetAllCategoriesByParentCategoryId(parentId).Select(c => c.ID).ToList();
  var products= _productService.SearchProducts(categoryIds: ctgyIds, storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id, orderBy: ProductSortingEnum.NameAsc).AsEnumerable().Select(p => new
  {
    ID = p.ID,
    Text = p.Name.Substring(m.Name.IndexOf(' ') + 1)
  });
  return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and the script

```
$("#Supplier").change(function () {
  var pID = $(this).val();
  var select = $("#Product").empty().append($('<option/>').text('Select A Product'));
  if (pID == '0') { return; } // this should really be testing for null or undefined but thats an issue with your first select          
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadProductsBySupplier", "CoaLookup")', { parentId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
      select.append($('<option/>').val(item.ID).text(item.Text);
    });
  });
});
```

Note also in the script the `if` clause  before `$.getJSON` - there is not much point calling the server then deciding to ignore the return value

Comment: Thanks a ton Stephen and I really appreciate you giving me tips on how to improve the code. I always try to look for such advice

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected value in Edit page try using:

```
@Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(ViewBag.Product, "Id","Name", item.Id))
```

in this the  item.Id is the selected value, and ViewBag.Product you have to fill it from your products using linq for example in the Controller.