# The ViewData item that has the key 'CountryId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ienumerable

Well there are many questions asked on this topic and I went through many of them but unfortunately I did not found any solutions for my problem. I want to auto-populate my dropdown list of **Countries**, **State**, **Cities** from DB. Below is my model I designed.

**Model:**

```
    public class Registration
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please Select a Country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCountries { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a State")]
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableStates { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a City")]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCities { get; set; }
    }
```

When a new user logs in I redirect him to registration page of user Controller.

Below is my Get **ActionResult** of User Controller

```
 public ActionResult Registration()
    {
        UserModel.Registration userreg = new UserModel.Registration();

        try
        {
            userreg.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select your Country", Value = "Countries" });
            var query = from countries in user.Countries orderby countries select countries;
            var content = query.ToList();
            foreach (var country in content)
            {
                userreg.AvailableCountries.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = country.Name,
                    Value = country.Id.ToString()
                });
            }
            return View(userreg);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Helpers.Functions_ErrorLog.LogMessage("Error from User/Registration - " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return View(userreg);

    }
```

This is my **Registration View**

```
    @model I_am_a_Fresher.Models.UserModel.Registration
    @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formstep1", @class = "active" }))
        {
            <div id="stepsbody" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12 mar-top-22">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="ico-state-city"></span>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId, null, new { @class = "text-danger error-bold" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <span class="ico-state-city"></span>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.AvailableStates)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StateId, null, new { @class = "text-danger error-bold" })
                        <span id="states-loading-progress" style="display: none;">Please wait..</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
    }
```

Why I get this error I am not clear. This should work according to me. Can anyone suggest why this error is coming?

Comment: "This should work according to me."  Classic.

Comment: Are you getting this error on initial load or just when you post back?

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. On initial load itself..

Comment: Debug your code. Your not setting `userreg.AvailableCountries = new List<SelectListItem>` so your getting an exception which still returns the view, but `AvailableCountries` is null

Comment: I have not included any javascripts functions as of now because on page load itself I am getting this error..

Comment: change the value="Countries" to value=-1

Comment: @StephenMuecke.  oh.. Do I need to set it in model or can I set it in ActionResult Registration?

Comment: @HadiHassan, Whats that got to do with it. The message is because `AvailableCountries` is `null`

Comment: In either a parameter-less constructor in the model or in the controller - makes no difference so long as you initialize it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke.. Nice buddy.. worked like a magic... Thanks.. Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding `SelectListItems` to `AvailableCountries` inside a `try` block, but the property has not been initialized so an exception is thrown. You then return the view but `AvailableCountries` is still `null` which results in the error message you are seeing.

Either initialize it in a parameter-less constructor in the model

```
public class Registration
{
  public Registration()
  {
    AvailableCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
  }
  ....
}
```

or in the controller method

```
UserModel.Registration userreg = new UserModel.Registration();
userreg.AvailableCountries = new List<SelectListItem>();
try
  .....
```

However I would suggest you change the model property to

```
public SelectList AvailableCountries { get; set; }
```

and the controller to (2 lines of code vs 10)

```
var query = (from countries in user.Countries orderby countries select countries).ToList();
userreg.AvailableCountries = new SelectList(query, "Id", "Name");
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.AvailableCountries, "Please Select your Country")
```

which renders the first option as "Please Select your Country" but without a `value` attribute which is more appropriate

Note also you will need to initialise an empty `SelectList` for `AvailableStates` and `AvailableCities` assuming they are being populated using javascript/jquery

```
userreg.AvailableStates = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
```

Comment: And in case you need any help with the jquery [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556718/html-dropdownlistfor-confusion/26557347#26557347)

Comment: Thats more helpful. I need one small help. How can I disable the first option through jquery now? say here I want to disable "Please select your country"..

Comment: Its the first option in the select, so (assuming you want to disable it the first time the user selected something some other option) `$('#CountryId').change(function() { $(this).children('option').first().prop('disabled', true); });` (or you could do `.first().remove();` to remove it but you would need to do this in a `$('form).one('change', '#CountryId', function() {..` so it does it once only