# Controller action method's model parameter is empty when form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an action Method ReleasingTheaters in Movie controller, The ReleasingTheaters has two overload one is  httpGet which accepts the Movie Id and do stuff and return the ReleasingTheaters View which accepts a ViewModel object .On the ReleasingTheaters view when I submit the form by clicking the submit button ,controller's another http Post action Method ReleasingTheaters accepts the viewModel and save model data to database.

Here is my viewModel :

```
 public class MovieReleasingTheatersViewModel
 {
    public MovieReleasingTheatersViewModel()
    {
        AvailableStates = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvailableCities = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvailableLocations = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ReleasingTheaters = new List<MovieReleasingTheaterModel>();
    }

    [Display(Name="State")]
    public int? StateId { get; set; }  
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableStates { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableCities { get; set; }
    public int? LocationId { get; set; }
    public IList<SelectListItem> AvailableLocations { get; set; }
    public IList<MovieReleasingTheaterModel> ReleasingTheaters { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Control :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ReleasingTheaters(int id)
    {
        var model = new MovieReleasingTheatersViewModel();

        model = PrepareMovieReleasingTheaterModel(0, 0, 0, id);

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ReleasingTheaters(MovieReleasingTheatersViewModel model)
    {
        // iterate through the model's collection and save or update database
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Here is my ReleasingTheaters View:

```
 @model Bookmany.Admin.Models.Movie.MovieReleasingTheatersViewModel

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Releasing Theaters";
  }

<h3>Releasing Theaters</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateId, Model.AvailableStates, "Select  State")

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId, Model.AvailableCities, "Select City")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LocationId, Model.AvailableLocations, "Select Location")
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="table">
<thead class="t_head">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Theater
        </th>
        <th>
            Date From
        </th>
        <th>
            Date To
        </th>
        <th>
            Release
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="t_body">
    @foreach (var item in Model.ReleasingTheaters)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TheaterName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.DateFrom, new { id = "DateFrom" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.DateTo, new { id = "DateTo" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.IsTheaterChecked)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div> 
    }
```

My problem :

When I click the submit button the Model object on action method has no value, the viewModel object's collection properties all is empty whats wrong with my code

How do I get the model object values(collection) on my action method hence that I can save or update that values back to my database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `foreach` to a `for` loop so that the controls are correctly named and can be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ReleasingTheaters.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ReleasingTheaters[i].DateFrom)
  ....
}
```

This will generate inputs such as

```
<input type="text" name="ReleasingTheaters[0].DateFrom" id="ReleasingTheaters_0__DateFrom" value="?" >
<input type="text" name="ReleasingTheaters[1].DateFrom" id="ReleasingTheaters_1__DateFrom" value="?" >
```

Note also that you should not be setting the `id` attribute with `new { id = "DateFrom" }` etc. The helpers will render a unique id but you are creating duplicate id's which is invalid html

Comment: ,when I removed the code new { id = "DateFrom" } the jquery Ui datapicker wont display at all I referenced the DateFrom id as :<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DateFrom").datepicker();
        $("#DateTo").datepicker();
       
    });
</script> .Then how do I reference the controls for displaying the datepicker?

Comment: Then use class names. `new { @class = "datepicker" }` and `$(".datepicker").datepicker()` (duplicate id's are invalid html)

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke , thank you this save my day .I marked your answer

Comment: I would like to know your opinion about in the above approach ,where I populate the AvailableCities drop down and t_body (table body) when  AvailableStates drop down value changes via ajax method call into the server ,is there a better approach there

Comment: If the list of `AvailableCities` is dependent on the selection of `AvailableStates`, then yes, an ajax that returns JSON to populate the 2nd dropdown is the best approach (ditto for 3rd dropdown, although it might be better to returns a partial view for the table). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556718/html-dropdownlistfor-confusion/26557347#26557347) gives an example of populating dropdowns using ajax calls

Comment: @Stphen Muecke , Is it possible to do when the AvailableStates changes 1) call ajax and return jason and populate AvailableCities ddl 2)and populate table by returning a partial view in a single  call .How ?

Comment: @Mussammil, Yes, that's what the code in the other answer is doing (click link in my last comment)

Comment: , when the form is submitted to the httpPost action ReleasingTheater the ReleasingTheaters property TheaterName is null I display that property in my view as   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>modelItem.ReleasingTheaters[i].TheaterName)

Comment: `DisplayFor` does not render a control that posts back. You can add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ReleasingTheaters[i].TheaterName)` to create a hidden input or use `TextBoxFor` and add `new { @readonly="readonly" }` instead of `DisplayFor()`