# How can I get value textbox inside partial view in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

How can I get value of @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Sales) in partial view after pass to controller

**My partial view** :

```
@model IEnumerable<PG.Admin.Models.Items.ItemViewModel>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().ItemId)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Sales)
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Sales)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Your need to use a `for` loop. [Refer example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571133/controller-action-methods-model-parameter-is-empty-when-form-submit/26571182#26571182)

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke I'm using list view and create view in a same view I have foreach but I can't get value texboxfor item.Sales ? I don't know why :(

Comment: Do you read my comment and look at the linked answer. You can't use a `foreach` loop. It needs to be a `for` loop!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why don't use foreach for this issue ???

Comment: Read the linked answer! It explains why.