# How to use viewmodel (IEnumerable) to update my database in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The `{WV_DeviceReg, WV_DevEventLog, WV_DevSystemLog, WV_DeviceConfig}` are my models from ADO.NET Entity Framework.

ViewModel

```
namespace MvcWebVms.Models
{
    public class HomeViewModels
    {
        public IEnumerable<WV_DeviceReg> DeviceReg { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<WV_DevEventLog> DevEventLog { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<WV_DevSystemLog> DevSystemLog { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<WV_DeviceConfig> DeviceConfig { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model MvcWebVms.Models.HomeViewModels

@using (Html.BeginForm()){

    <div>

       @foreach (var item in Model.DeviceConfig) {

             @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FieldName)
             @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.DeviceID_F)

            <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FieldName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.FieldValue)
            </div>

        } 
        <input type="submit" value="Apply" />

    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Setting(string id)
{
    HomeServices service = new HomeServices();
    return View(service.GetDeviceSettingAT(id));
}

public WVDBEntities wvdb = new WVDBEntities();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Setting(HomeViewModels viewModels)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    foreach (????????????)
        {
           ????????????????
        }
        wvdb.SaveChanges();
        return View(viewModels);
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Table

```
WV_DeviceConfig { FieldName(PK), DeviceID_F(PK), FieldValue, ServerTime }
```

Key of FieldName Mapping value of FieldValue

Q: How to use `foreach` to update my database, please?

Comment: I'm tempted to put an answer that says "Stephen Muecke knows the answer"

Comment: Since all the properties of `viewModels` will be empty when you post back, lets address that issue first. You need to use an `EditorTemplate` for each type or use a `for` loop to render your controls (and change the collections from `IEnumerable` to `IList`). [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26571133/controller-action-methods-model-parameter-is-empty-when-form-submit/26571182#26571182) explains the issue. (LOL @AbdulAhmad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you want to change your foreach loop to a traditional for loop and post back a List like so:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.DeviceConfig.Count(); i ++) {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceConfig[i].FieldName)
 //etc.. same thing for all hidden/input fields
```

and your action method can accept a list like so

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Setting(List<DeviceConfig> DeviceConfigList)
```

and then you can do the following to update the database

```
foreach (var item in DeviceConfigList)
    {
      db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Assume OP wants to post back whole model so method parameter should be `HomeViewModels model` and then `foreach (var item in model.DeviceConfigList) {...`